# How to do $ \int -x \sec(2x) dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I know how to solve integration by parts of some functions, but I came across the integration of $-x\sec(2x)$, and I can't solve it. I put the question on an [online calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28-xsec2x%29). I got the answer, but I can't understand the logic behind solving it. Why it used hyperbolic function. I've never solved any question like this before. Isn't there any other way to solve it? What is the logic behind all the substitutions?

How would you integrate $-x\sec(2x)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take care afterward.

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: Note that $(\tan(x))' = \sec^2(x)$ and use integration by parts to get $-x\tan(x) +\int \tan(x) dx$

Comment: The one who edited it before changed the double angle to the power of `sec`. It is `sec2x`.

Comment: I can see dilogarithms $\operatorname{Li}_2$ but not hyperbolic functions in the solution. See also the [Wolfram Alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+-x+sec%5B2x%5D).

Comment: @Gary I am not saying the solution has hyperbolic functions. When you open the link mentioned in the question, you'll see sec2x replace with its hyperbolic form.

Comment: @Gary click the link and then click the go button in front of the eqn. box. Scroll down and click show steps. There you will find it.

Comment: The minus sign and the $2$ are unnecessary complications. The real problem here is how to integrate $x\sec x$.

Comment: @TonyK it's the actual problem. Integrating xsecx is easy, but how to integrate xsec2x is the actual question.

Comment: They are the same problem. Just substitute $u=2x$ to turn one into the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough sketch (without checks, tracking branches of log etc).

Assuming we can use integration by parts and pulling minus outside the integral:
$$\int x \sec{\left(2 x \right)}\, dx = x \int \sec{\left(2 x \right)}\, dx - \iint \sec{\left(2 x \right)}\, dx\, dx$$
tansforming $\sec(2x)$ to function of $\tan$ and using $\tan(x) = t$ substitution
$$ \int \sec{\left(2 x \right)}\, dx = \int \frac{1 + \tan^{2}{\left(x \right)} }{1 - \tan^{2}{\left(x \right)}}\, dx = \int \frac{1}{1 - t^{2}}\, dt = \frac{- \log{\left(x - 1 \right)} + \log{\left(x + 1 \right)}}{2} $$
so after substituting back to first integral
$$ \int x \sec{\left(2 x \right)}\, dx = \frac{x \left(- \log{\left(\tan{\left(x \right)} - 1 \right)} + \log{\left(\tan{\left(x \right)} + 1 \right)}\right)}{2} - \int \frac{- \log{\left(\tan{\left(x \right)} - 1 \right)} + \log{\left(\tan{\left(x \right)} + 1 \right)}}{2}\, dx. $$

Considering the second integral, without the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor, there are two integrals to solve:
$$ - \int \log{\left(\tan{\left(x \right)} - 1 \right)}\, dx $$ and $$ \int \log{\left(\tan{\left(x \right)} + 1 \right)}\, dx $$
which look [quite](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integral%20log%28tan%28x%29%20-%201%29) [complicated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integral%20log%28tan%28x%29%20%2B%201%29), but they at least give the idea where does the dilogarithms come from.

Alternative forms of $ \int \sec{\left(2 x \right)}\, dx $ that could be tried:
$$\frac{\log{\left(\tan{\left(2 x \right)} + \sec{\left(2 x \right)} \right)}}{2}$$
and
$$ \frac{- \log{\left(\sin{\left(2 x \right)} - 1 \right)} + \log{\left(\sin{\left(2 x \right)} + 1 \right)}}{4}$$
or piecewise acoth(t) and atanh(t) depending on value of $t$, if hyperbolic functions are wanted. Finally more care is requred to solve it generally and not loose track of the branch of logarithm, check what conditions on $x$ do these transformations impose etc.

Anyway, the resulting integrals (that would have to be integrated over dx after the integration by parts) aren't really much easier (such as $\log(\sin(2x) + 1), \log(\cos(2x)), \log(\tan(x))$ etc.). Surprisingly, Integral Calculator can do some of them step-by-step, so it can be followed how to get them.